# How do you show table view ONLY when search bar is clicked?

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, xcode, uitableview

I only want to show the table view only when the search bar is clicked (like instagram). If anyone knows how to do this, any information would be helpful.

Here's the relevant code that I have:

```
class UserSearchController: UICollectionViewController, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout,UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchDisplayDelegate {

let cellId = "cellId"

let searchBar: UISearchBar = {
    let sb = UISearchBar()
    sb.placeholder = "Search"
    return sb
}()

fileprivate func setupNavBarAndSearchBar() {

    let navBar = navigationController?.navigationBar
    searchBar.delegate = self
    navigationController?.navigationBar.addSubview(searchBar)
    //Constraints already figured^^
}


func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)}

func searchBarSearchButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)

}

func searchBarCancelButtonClicked(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {
    searchBar.resignFirstResponder()
    searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
    searchBar.text = ""
}


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    setupNavBarAndSearchBar()
    collectionView?.backgroundColor = .white
    collectionView?.register(UserProfileVideoCell.self, forCellWithReuseIdentifier: cellId)
  searchBar.addSubview(SearchUsersTv) **Compiles error "expected argument type UIView"**
}
```

Here's what I have for the file "SearchUsersTv" :

```
class SearchUsersTv: UIView, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {
let cellId = "cellId"

var tableView = UITableView()

let screenHeight = UIScreen.main.bounds.height
let screenWidth = UIScreen.main.bounds.width

override init(frame: CGRect){
    super.init(frame: frame)

    setup()
    tableView.delegate = self
    tableView.dataSource = self
    tableView.register(UITableViewCell.self, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")
}
func setup() {

    self.backgroundColor = UIColor.black

    tableView = UITableView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth*0.5, height: screenHeight))
    tableView.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.black.cgColor
    self.addSubview(tableView)
}

required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return 10
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: cellId, for: indexPath)
    cell.backgroundColor = .magenta
    return cell
}
```

> Now this file above doesn't run since it's not running (it compiles an
>   error when I try to add this as a sub view in the first file)

Comment: Set your `tableView`'s `isHidden` property to `true` in `viewDidLoad`, and set it to `false` in `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing`. You should set it back to `true` in `searchBarCancelButtonClicked`.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed but how do I add a table view on the top of the collection views?

Comment: You're adding your table view programmatically, so you'll need to add its constraints programmatically too.

Comment: Do I add the table view as a subView? with like : "view.addSubview(searchUsersTableView)" ?

Comment: @ErikBatista Yes, you add it normally, and then you set its constraints.

Comment: @MoeAbdul-Hameed thank you, I got it working. But now the table view seems to not scroll or click. But thank you again, I'll find a way to fix this!

Answer (score 0):

Make Your TableView alpha value to "0" first in your StoryBoard.

simply make it "1.0" in your

```
func searchBarTextDidBeginEditing(_ searchBar: UISearchBar) {searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(true, animated: true)}
```

like this

```
tableView.alpha = 1.0
```

Hope this helps.It Solved my problem also.

Comment: @Erik Please accept this answer if it resolves your issue.